# android push notification not working

Tags: java, android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

i created an android app which uses push notification, but everytime i send a notification from backend a dialog pops up on my android tablet saying "unfortunately lic has stopped". i tried troubleshooting the app but can seem to get where the error is coming from.

I've added the following permissions in my Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission
    android:name="com.example.myappname.pemermission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.myappname.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

I've also registered a receiver to handle the messages:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.example.myappname.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="com.example.myappname"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And finally, I've declared a new `meta-data` tag:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
<activity android:name="noti_handler"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
```

My `Broadcastreceiver` code is the following :

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver   {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg) {
    String sh = gcm.getMessageType(arg);
    Bundle bb= arg.getExtras();
    if(!bb.isEmpty()){
    if(GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(sh)){
    String b=arg.getExtras().getString("message")+"<br>";
        String f="handler";

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos=openFileOutput(f, con.MODE_APPEND);
            fos.write(b.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ef) {
            error(ef.toString());
            ef.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            error(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            error(ex.toString());
        }

        sendNoti("you have a message/s");//this sends notification to user
    try{

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
    }

    }
    }
}


}
```

Comment: post logcat buddy.....

Comment: i am working from device not emulator and i cant seem to debug the app on my samsung galaxy tab3- cant get the oem driver from samsung website

Answer (score 0):

Add that line in your `onReceive` method:

```
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
```

You have a null pointer execption on the 4th line.

**Edit:**

Change:

```
<activity android:name="noti_handler"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
```

To :

```
<activity android:name="com.example.myappname.noti_handler"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
```

And

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.myappname.pemermission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

To :

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.myappname.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Comment: i already did this in my oncreate method-and i just put it in my GcmBroadcastReceiver class but i still get the same dialog showing up everytime i send a push notification to my device

Comment: Please post your whole class.

Comment: made the changes still not working-changing the name of my noti_handler activity caused an error in  manifest file should end with ">" not "/>"

Comment: should i still post my whole class? really need to get this app working